# how do i get input for undefined number of self referential structures?

Tags: c, structure

i need to get names for undefined number of students which is set as a member of a self referential structure. i have a pseudo-code and the actual code set up but no matter what i give, the input loop stops at the third time. can anyone help?

pseudo code:

```
while name != 0
scan name
current student name = name
current student score = random
current = current -> next
```

actual code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define DEBUG 1

struct Student{
    char name[30];
    double score;

    struct Student* next;
};

int main(void){
    char n[30];
    int i = 0;
    struct Student s;
    struct Student *head = &s, *current;
    current = head;
    while(i < 4){//4 times for debugging
        scanf(" %s",n);
        strcpy(current->name,n);
        current -> score = 100;
        current = current->next;
        if(DEBUG) printf("100\n");
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the result i get :

```
input1
100
input2

press any key to continue
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `current = current->next`. Run in a debugger and check what value `next` is. Or just think about it by looking at the code and where `next` is used and set.

Comment: huh, enabled the dev c++ debugger and it gave me a segmentation fault. i thought the 'next' referred to the next available address for the structure?

Comment: @Alex  you have to make sure `next` is pointing valid memory, it won't come flying out from nowhere.

Comment: Code can only do what you tell it to. Since you never assigned anything to `next` (and it is an auto var) then it will be unintialised meaning it contains an undefined value and accessing it results in undefined behaviour. You need to create a new `struct Student` for each new entry and do the necessary linking. Dynamic allocations (e.g. `malloc`) are the usual way of making new elements.

Comment: thanks @kaylum and kiranBiradar. i solved it by using malloc. i guess computers really have to be told what to do anything!

Comment: _Ii guess computers really have to be told what to do anything_: your guess is correct.